# Timing constraint Failure FPGA

Tags: fpga, clock, xilinx, xilinx-ise

I am trying to implement a design, I got from my Ex-Colleague. It is a huge design working with clock frequency 200MHz; simulations, synthesis, translation, mapping all goes fine while after place and route, it gives an error of "timing constraint failure" in Summary and leads to the following constraint failure.

> NET "lbus_clkn" TNM_NET = "clkin_grp"; TIMESPEC "TS_clkin" = PERIOD :
>   "clkin_grp" : 41.666 ns HIGH 50.0%;

When I have a look at the timing report, I found this.

> Release 14.7 Trace  (nt64)   Copyright (c) 1995-2013 Xilinx, Inc. 
>   All rights reserved.     Device,package,speed:
>   xc7k160t,fbg676,C,-1 (PRODUCTION 1.10 2013-10-13)   Report level:
>   verbose report 
>       Environment Variable      Effect    --------------------      ------    NONE                      No environment variables were set   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------  INFO:Timing:3412 - To improve timing, see the Timing Closure User
>   Guide (UG612).   INFO:Timing:2752 - To get complete path coverage, use
>   the unconstrained paths
>       option. All paths that are not constrained will be reported in the
>       unconstrained paths section(s) of the report.   INFO:Timing:3339 - The clock-to-out numbers in this timing report are based on
>       a 50 Ohm transmission line loading model.  For the details of this model,
>       and for more information on accounting for different loading conditions,
>       please see the device datasheet. 
>       ================================================================================   Timing constraint: TS_clkin = PERIOD TIMEGRP "clkin_grp" 41.666 ns
>   HIGH 50%;   For more information, see Period Analysis in the Timing
>   Closure User Guide (UG612).    204018317633 paths analyzed, 82474
>   endpoints analyzed, 0 failing endpoints    0 timing errors detected.
>   **(0 setup errors, 0 hold errors, 0 component switching limit errors)**
>
> ### Minimum period is  17.382ns.

If there is 0 setup error here then why is it showing timing constraint failed in summary. I cannot trace the error. How to debug, what is the root cause of this failure?